# Add data to the TemplateField in asp.net from text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi want add data to the row from text boxers How i can do this so far i do like this
This is my grid view `

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GVDisplay" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="Silver" BorderColor="#660033" BorderStyle="Solid" 
        Height="211px" CellSpacing="1"  Font-Bold="False" 
        Width="502px">

        <Columns>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number of Mails">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TXTno_ofmails" runat="server" Width="100"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtremarks" runat="server" Width="100"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
   </asp:TemplateField>

    </asp:GridView>
```

This is my C# code
I have design form and i want add text boxers values to grid from button click

```
 protected void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          DataRow dr;
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
          dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));



          dr = dt.NewRow();


          TxtNumOfMails.Text //My text box name
          TxtRemarks.Text // My Text box name

          dt.Rows.Add(dr);
          GVDisplay.DataSource = dt;
          GVDisplay.DataBind();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and please close column tag.

```
    protected void btnsubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));



        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Column1"] = TxtNumOfMails.Text;
        dr["Column2"] = TxtRemarksss.Text;


        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        GVDisplay.DataSource = dt;
        GVDisplay.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: is this insert to the template field textboxers

Comment: really first code was for windowsforms try this out may this helps you solve your problem